# const char [ len ] loses 1 length, element after concatenation ( being the source string, 2nd argument )

Tags: c

```
char string1 [] = "/8-|";
const char string2 [ 5 ] = "/8-|";
```

Why does this:

```
printf ( "%zu", strlen ( string2 ) );
```

show **4**, and after doing this:

```
printf ( "%s", strncat ( string1, string2, 4 ) );
printf ( "%zu", strlen ( string2 ) );
```

*-* it turns **3** ?

Comment: `const char string2 [ 5 ] = "/8-|"` is wrong, as this array contains 6 characters - the 5 that are explicitly stated, plus the null (0) character, which you don't see, but the compiler (or preprocessor) adds implicitly.

Comment: `strncat ( string1, string2, 4 )` attempts at most 4 characters plus a terminator to the end of  `string1` .  Since you didn't allocate enough space for those 5 more characters, the results are undefined.

Comment: I can only see 4 chars

Comment: `string1` has 5 bytes of data stored. As you do not explicitly mention the size, the size is deduced from the string you initialize it with. With `strncat` you are trying to append more bytes to `string1` than it has space for. You should not be doing this in the first place. Having said that, I can only *assume* that as you concatenate, you start overwriting the value of `string2` with the last three characters of `string2`. Hence you get the length as `3`.

Comment: Gave string 1 more space, worked.

Comment: It just worked for now. It might not work always on different machines. Maybe you could define `string2` before `string1` and check if that works.

Comment: It didn't "work", you just think it did. You're invoking *undefined behavior*.  I strongly advise you turn up all warnings to pedantic levels, treat them as error (because that is exactly what they are), and run your code in both a debugger *and* an address sanitizer.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb <`const char string2 [ 5 ] = "/8-|"` is wrong> is unclear as `"/8-|"` is size 5, not 6.

Comment: You can't learn string handling in C by trial and error. You need to use conventional study materials to learn about arrays, pointers and strings, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this: `printf ( "%zu", strlen ( string2 ) );` show 4 ...

Because the *length* of the *string* in `string2[]` is 4.

---

Later:
`strncat( string1, string2, 4 )` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `string1` is not big enough for 4 additional characters.

The rest of code is irrelevant as UB occurred.